# driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("Hello") not working for latest chrome driver- Selenium Webdriver -java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("Hello")
```

The above code for prompt is not working for latest chrome driver with selenium webdriver -java. It didn't throw any error. Except sendkeys all other actions accept(),dismiss() , getText() is working well. I have used ChromeDriver 2.29, selenium-3.3.1, Chrome Browser - Version 56.0.2924.87.

Comment: Roll back to chromedriver v2.28

Comment: Enter it as a bug in Chrome Driver.

Answer (score 0):

google chrome 
Version 59.0.3071.109 
chrome driver 2.30
selenium 3.4
i have this version for chrome.

driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("Helllo") 
is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

This is purely a display issue and the input of sendKeys(...) will be sent after you accept the Alert.

See also the answer in this Chromium issue:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1120#c11